# VC++ 2010 Linker /VERBOSE option doesn't work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have installed a package from Intel, and I was able to get it working. It is a VC++ 2010 project. 
I know that it works fine, and I was able to produce some output that I was expecting.
Since there are lots of files being linked, I wanted to turn on the verbose flag and see what is going on, but I am not sure why nothing gets displayed when I run in the verbose mode.

In property page, under `"Linker-->General"` I set
`Show Progress --> "Display all progress messages (/VERBOSE)`, and under `"Linker-->Advanced"`, I added /VERBOSE to the "Additional Options", just like this:
`Additional Options --> "/machine:x64 /debug /VERBOSE"`

Do I need to do something else? Cause nothing is being displayed, as if I am not even in VERBOSE mode!!!

Comment: Maybe try under tools->options->Projects and SOlutions->Build and Run, change the last 2 settings for output from 'Minimal' to 'Diagnostic' verbosity? It's possible verbose linker messages are being filtered because of this setting

Comment: I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Do you know where to look for the output?